# Strange error with ccsm (fedora 16) 32 - bit

Tags: fedora

I don't know if anyone else has experienced this, and I'm not sure what information you need (please ask if there is anything), but ccsm keep crashing because

> /usr/bin/python keeps getting killed by signal 11 (sigsegv).

Is this a known issue, can I do anything to fix this?  I have researched other bugs, and none seem to match this one

```
[...@localhost ~]$ ccsm
Backend     : ini
Integration : true
Profile     : default
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ccm/Window.py:92: Warning: g_object_set_qdata: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.LeftPane.pack_start(page.LeftWidget,   True, True)
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ccm/Window.py:95: Warning: g_object_set_qdata: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.show_all()
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ccm/Widgets.py:1570: Warning: g_object_set_qdata: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self._table.attach (button, col, col+1, row, row+1, 0, xpadding=TableX, ypadding=TableY)
Loading icons...
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ccm/Widgets.py:1575: Warning: g_object_set_qdata: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.show_all ()
Initializing compiztoolbox options...done
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: I ran it in the terminal and it is definitely segfaulting is anyone else having this issue?

Comment: I found some bug reports that might be similar, but I can't find a solution